# activerecord-sqlserver-adapter conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I'm trying to install sql server adapter on Ruby using:

gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

The isntallation was ok but when I try to run:

mongify check database.config

to validate my database.config file to copy data from SQL server to MongoDB I get this error:

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1638:in `raise_if_
conflicts': Please install the sqlserver adapter:`gem install activerecord-sqls
erver-adapter` (Unable to activate activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.1.0, because
 activerecord-3.2.19 conflicts with activerecord (~> 4.1.0))

How can update or uninstall activerecord-3.2.19  to use the new one?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue. Uninstalled activerecord gem entirely, reinstalled mongify, but same problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have the wrong version of activerecord-sqlserver-adapter. What I did to solve this was uninstall the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gem:

```
"gem uninstall activerecord-sqlserver-adapter"
```

and then reinstalled version 3.2

```
"gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter -v 3.2"
```

and you'll most likely have to install tiny_tds

```
"gem install tiny_tds"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.2.15)`, `tiny_tds (1.0.5 x64-mingw32)` and `mongify (1.3.0)`, with ruby *2.3.1p112* and gem *2.6.7*. activerecord-sqlserver-adapter depends on `activemodel (4.2.7.1)` and `activerecord (4.2.7.1)`. I also had a higher version of these gems. This fixed it:

```
gem uninstall activerecord -v 5.0.0.1
gem uninstall activemodel -v 5.0.0.1
```

However, hardest part was the `database.config`

```
sql_connection do
  adapter       "sqlserver"
  database      "DbName"
  host          "<sql_server_ip>"
  username      "<valid_user_and_login>"
  password      "<sql_server_password>"  
end
```